# React add active class to click element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state

I want add active class to click element but it is toogle. How can i fixed it?

```
const PodcastTab = () => {
const [tabOpened, setTabOpened] = useState(false);

  return <div>
      <div>
          <span className={classNames('my-podcast',{'active':tabOpened})} onClick={()=>{setTabOpened(!tabOpened)}}>My Podcast</span>
          <span className={classNames('podcasts-stats',{'active':!tabOpened})} onClick={()=>{setTabOpened(!tabOpened)}}>Podcast's Stats</span>
          <div className="my-podcast-tab">
                <Podcast />
            </div>
            <div className="podcasts-stats-tab">
                <Podcast imgURL="https://i.picsum.photos/id/144/75/75.jpg?hmac=9kweqWXv0sL19dFj1CaMKxbH3kQMIuFFbHy2hWhKJ4w" status="x" title="y"/>
            </div>
      </div>
      
  </div>;
}
```

Comment: This should work. Please post your whole code.

Comment: @PrateekThapa I updated, can you see? When I click the same element twice, it adds active class to the other element

Comment: Your code looks okay. Try creating a sandbox.

Comment: @PrateekThapa can you look at my new question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036219/react-infinite-scroll-scrollabletarget-get-id-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following className:

```
className={classNames('podcasts-stats',{tabOpened ? 'active' : ''})}
```